# Do I need to dispose resources on app close (kill)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, memory

I'm developing a Flutter application, and I was wondering if I need to dispose of the app resources when the user closes (kills) it manually.

For instance, If I'm managing an HTTP Client within the app, do I need to dispose of it on app close?

**Does an app manual kill will release its resources automatically?**

Is it the same behavior for both Android and IOS?

Looking for official documented answer.

Comment: Afaik when an app is closed all the memory allocated to it would be cleared, so it wouldn’t matter even if you don’t dispose it. Disposing particularly helps when you app is running and you don’t want unneeded resources to hog the memory

Comment: I thought the same, but I can't find any official document that confirms this issue :/

Comment: I really don't understand why someone will downvote this question. It's legitimate.

Comment: Seems like an interesting question, considering all background and foreground tasks, I am nit expecting answer to be simple. Upvoted to balance it